# listing of vectors satisfying some special constraint

Tags: list-manipulation, constraint

We have

`list = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 0}, {1,-1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1},{-1, 0, -1},{0, -1, 1},{0, 1, -1},{0, -1, -1}}`

`list2 ={{2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {-2, 0, 0}, {0,-2, 0}, {0, 0, -2}}`

1st Problem: I would like to obtain the list of all possible distinct three vectors from the list where the sum of these vectors gives the zero vector.

For example:  `{1, 1, 0}+{-1, 0, 1}+{0, -1, -1}=={0,0,0}`.  Hence, `{1, 1, 0},{-1, 0, 1},{0, -1, -1}` are one of three vectors which we want in our list.

2nd Problem: I would like to obtain the list of all possible distinct four vectors (no duplication is allowed) such that three vectors will be selected from the list, and one vector will be selected from list2 and the sum of these 4 vectors gives the zero vector.

For example: `{{2,0,0},{1,1,0},{-1,-1,0},{-1,0,1},{-1,0,-1}}` is in our list,
where `{2,0,0}` is selected from list2, and the other 3 vectors are selected from the list.

Comment: For large lists where brute-force enumeration might be impractical, this might be best cast as an Integer Linear Programming problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want duplicates (i.e., pick each 3-list at most once) and don't want permutations (i.e., only ordered solutions),

```
Select[Subsets[list, {3}], Total[#] == {0, 0, 0} &]
(*    {{{1, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, -1, -1}},
       {{1, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, -1}, {0, -1, 1}},
       {{1, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, 0}, {0, -1, -1}},
       {{1, 0, 1}, {-1, -1, 0}, {0, 1, -1}},
       {{0, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, -1}},
       {{0, 1, 1}, {-1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, -1}},
       {{-1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, -1}, {0, -1, 1}},
       {{1, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, -1}}}    *)
```

There are only 8 such solutions. Permuting these will give @UlrichNeumann's 48 solutions.

For the second problem, we check if the sum of three vectors is in `-list2`:

```
Select[Subsets[list, {3}], MemberQ[-list2, Total[#]] &]
(*    {{{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, -1, -1}},
       {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 0, -1}},
       {{1, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, -1, 1}},
       {{1, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, -1}},
       {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, -1}, {0, -1, 1}},
       {{1, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, -1}, {0, -1, -1}},
       {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, -1, 0}},
       {{1, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 1}},
       {{1, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, -1}},
       {{1, 0, 1}, {1, -1, 0}, {0, 1, -1}},
       {{1, 0, 1}, {-1, -1, 0}, {0, -1, -1}},
       {{0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, -1}},
       {{0, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, 1}},
       {{0, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, -1}},
       {{0, 1, 1}, {-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, -1}},
       {{-1, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, -1, -1}},
       {{-1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, -1}, {0, -1, -1}},
       {{-1, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, -1}, {0, -1, 1}},
       {{1, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, -1, -1}},
       {{1, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, -1}, {0, -1, 1}},
       {{1, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, -1}, {0, 1, -1}},
       {{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, -1}},
       {{-1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, -1}, {0, -1, 1}},
       {{-1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, -1}, {0, 1, -1}}}    *)
```

Comment: Thanks @Roman, I extended the problem with two lists. How can we adapt your code for the 2nd problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
list = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 0}, {1, -1,0}, {-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, -1}, {0, -1,1}, {0, 1, -1}, {0, -1, -1}};
```

All triple combinations:

```
triple = Tuples[list, 3]  
Select[triple, Total[#] == {0, 0, 0} &]
(*{{{1, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, -1, -1}}, 
{{1, 1, 0}, {-1,0, -1}, {0, -1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 1}, {-1, 0, -1}},...}*)
```

Mathematica finds 48 possibilities!

**Answer second question**

```
slist = Subsets[list, {3}];
Table[{li, Select[slist,Total[ #] == -li &]}, {li, list2}]
```

Comment: Thanks @Ulrich Neumann  I extended the problem with two lists. What do you suggest for solving  the 2nd problem, where duplication is not allowed

Comment: Many thanks for the second answer @Ulrich Neumann. I would like to ask  how can we improve your code (in a general sense) for the second answer. For instance, let say we want to take three vectors from list, and two vectors  from list2 for which sum of these will give zero vector (duplication is not allowed). In  general we choose "a" vectors from list, and "b" (b>1) vectors from list2.   So in this case 1st line of your  code will be   slist = Subsets[list, {a}]; But what will be the second part?

Comment: Perhaps `listb=Subsets[list2,{b}]` and `Table[{li, Select[slist,Total[ #] == -Total[li] &]}, {li, listb}]`?

Comment: Thanks @Ulrich Neumann, what about when duplication is allowed.
Particularly given an positive integer m,  How would the code change to find the all zero sums with m elements, where "a" vectors are selected from list and "b"  vectors from list2, where a+b=m. For instance: Let m=4. Case1:  2 elements from list2, 2 elements from list: {-2,0,0}+{0,-2,0}+2{1,1,0}={0,0,0}, here {1,1,0} is counted 2 times. Case2: 1 element from list2, 3 elements from list: {2,0,0}+{-1,-1,0}+{-1,0,-1}+{0,1,1}={0,0,0}. Case3: No element from list2, 4 elements from list,: {1,1,0}+{1,-1,0}+{-1,0,1}+{-1,0,-1}={0,0,0}.

Comment: In this case you probably have to use `Tuples` instead of `Subsets` I think.

Comment: Thanks @Ulrich Neumann,  I want to ask  about listing the results.I want to assign letters to each vectors in the list and list2,: list = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12}; where a1={1, 1, 0}, a2={1, 0, 1}, a3={0, 1, 1}, a4={-1, 1, 0}, a5={-1, -1, 0}, a6={-1, -1, 0} and so on and list2={b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6} where b1={2, 0, 0}, b2={0, 2, 0}, b3={0, 0, 2}, b4={-2, 0, 0}, b5={0, -2, 0}, b6={0, 0, -2}. For instance, if I have a result: {{ {2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}}, {{{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}}}}. I want the result in a form as {{ b1, b2} }, {{ a6, a6} }} How can we manage this

Comment: @gunes Perhaps `Association` is what you're looking for. Please ask a new question, if you need further assistance.