# Dropping specific elements from list

Tags: list-manipulation

`list[1] = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, -1}, {0, -1, 1}, {0, 1, -1}, {0, -1, -1}};` 
`list[2] = {{2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {-2, 0, 0}, {0, -2, 0}, {0,  0, -2}};`
@Ulrich Neumann gave algorithm  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/245764
which finds all combinations of these vectors summing to zero (duplication is allowed)
where "a" vectors are selected from `list[1]` and "b" vectors from `list[2].`

```
Moreover, I have the following code which @Bob Hanlon gave:
```

Clear["Global`*"]

```
Format[a[n_]] := Subscript[a, n];
Format[b[n_]] := Subscript[b, n];

list[1] = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 
    0}, {-1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, -1}, {0, -1, 1}, {0, 
    1, -1}, {0, -1, -1}};

list[2] = {{2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {-2, 0, 0}, {0, -2, 0}, {0, 
    0, -2}};
```

Create a replacement [`Rule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) for each list element

```
(repl[#] = 
    Thread[list[#] ->
      Array[{a, b}[[#]], Length[list[#]]]]) & /@ {1, 2}


sol[m_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{
   lista = Tuples[list[1], {m}],
   listb = Tuples[list[2], {n}]},
   Table[
   {li /. repl[2], Select[lista, Total[#] == -Total[li] &] /. repl[1]},
   {li, listb}]]
```

This code uses indexed variables  and express the  result of the code which  @Ulrich Neumann gave in terms of indexed variables.

Let me explain my problem with an example.  The above code, (when a=2 and b=2), `sol[2, 2]`
gives the following result:
[image: result when (when a=2 and b=2):]

I want to reduce the above list. For example, if  `a[1]` and `a[6]` is together in a result, then I just only this part to be eliminated. For instance, consider `{{b_1,b_4},{{a_1,a_6},{a_2,a_9},{a_3,a_12},{a_4,a_5},{a_5,a_4},{a_6,a_1},{a_7,a_8},{a_8,a_7},{a_9,a_2},{a_10,a_11},{a_11,a_10},{a_12,a_3}}}`

Here I just want `{a_1,a_6},` and `{a_6,a_1}` to be dropped. So, after dropping, this part will be in the form: `{{b_1,b_4},{{a_2,a_9},{a_3,a_12},{a_4,a_5},{a_5,a_4},{a_7,a_8},{a_8,a_7},{a_9,a_2},{a_10,a_11},{a_11,a_10},{a_12,a_3}}}` I want the same procedure through entire list given in the picture.

Consider the same example. This time I want all entire line to be removed when `b[1]` and `b[4]` is together.
So for example. `{{b_1,b_4},{{a_1,a_6},{a_2,a_9},{a_3,a_12},{a_4,a_5},{a_5,a_4},{a_6,a_1},{a_7,a_8},{a_8,a_7},{a_9,a_2},{a_10,a_11},{a_11,a_10},{a_12,a_3}}}` will be completely dropped. It is also same for  : `{{b_4,b_1},{{a_1,a_6},{a_2,a_9},{a_3,a_12},{a_4,a_5},{a_5,a_4},{a_6,a_1},{a_7,a_8},{a_8,a_7},{a_9,a_2},{a_10,a_11},{a_11,a_10},{a_12,a_3}}}` How can we manage these? I also look at the same problem in more general: sol[a,b], where a and b are different than 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** An alternative version which may be easier to generalize:

```
ClearAll[delete1b, delete2b]

delete1b = MapAt[DeleteCases[Alternatives @@ 
  ({OrderlessPatternSequence @ ##} & @@@ #2)], #, {All, 2}] &;

delete2b = DeleteCases[{Alternatives @@
  ({OrderlessPatternSequence @ ##} & @@@ #2), {__}}] @ # &;
```

***Examples:***

```
delete1b[sol[2, 2],{{a[1], a[6]}}] == delete1@{a[1], a[6]}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
delete1b[sol[2, 2], {{a[1], a[6]}, {a[3], a[12]}, {a[7], a[8]}}] == 
 delete1[Alternatives @@ {{a[1], a[6]}, {a[3], a[12]}, {a[7], a[8]}}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
delete2b[sol[2, 2], {{b[1], b[4]}}]== delete2@{b[1], b[4]}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
delete2b[sol[2, 2], {{b[1], b[2]}, {b[1], b[4]}, {b[3], b[4]}, {b[3], 
    b[4]}, {b[4], b[5]}, {b[4], b[6]}}] == 
 delete2[Alternatives @@ {{b[1], b[2]}, {b[1], b[4]}, {b[3], 
     b[4]}, {b[3], b[4]}, {b[4], b[5]}, {b[4], b[6]}}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
sol[3, 2] // Take[#, {2}] &
```

[image]

```
delete1b[sol[3, 2], {{a[6], a[7], ___}}] // Take[#, {2}] &
```

[image]

```
delete1b[sol[3, 2], {{a[6], a[9], ___}}] // Take[#, {2}] &
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[delete1, delete2]

delete1 = MapAt[DeleteCases[_?(MatchQ[#]@*Sort)], sol[2, 2], {All, 2}] &;
delete2 = DeleteCases[_?(MatchQ[#]@*Sort@*First)] @ sol[2, 2] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
delete1 @ {a[1], a[6]} // Column
```

[image]

```
delete1[Alternatives @@ {{a[1], a[6]}, {a[3], a[12]}, {a[7], a[8]}}] // Column
```

[image]

```
delete2 @ {b[1], b[4]} // Column
```

[image]

```
delete2[Alternatives @@  {{b[1], b[2]}, {b[1], b[4]}, {b[3], b[4]}, 
  {b[3], b[4]}, {b[4], b[5]}, {b[4], b[6]}}] // Column
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @kglr I want to ask how can we generalize your code. For example, let consider sol[a, b], where a =3 b=2.  For instance I want to drop the results which contains a_6 and a_7,  Sol[3,2] has one result:  {{b_1,b_2},{{a_6,a_7,a_12},{a_6,a_9,a_10},{a_6,a_10,a_9},{a_6,a_12,a_7},{a_7,a_6,a_12},{a_7,a_12,a_6},{a_9,a_6,a_10},{a_9,a_10,a_6},{a_10,a_6,a_9},{a_10,a_9,a_6},{a_12,a_6,a_7},{a_12,a_7,a_6}}}. After dropping the list will  be in form  {{b_1,b_2},{a_6,a_9,a_10},{a_6,a_10,a_9},{a_9,a_6,a_10},{a_9,a_10,a_6},{a_10,a_6,a_9},{a_10,a_9,a_6}}}. Also same type generalization for delete2 command.

Comment: @gunes, please see the update.

Comment: Many thanks for the update @kglr  I just want to ask one last thing. When we apply the code in the example delete1b[sol[3, 2], {{a[6], a[7], ___}}] // Take[#, {2}] &         we have the result:   {{{b_1,b_2},{{a_6,a_9,a_10},{a_6,a_10,a_9},{a_9,a_6,a_10},{a_9,a_10,a_6},{a_10,a_6,a_9},{a_10,a_9,a_6}}}} . In the final answer,   we have lots of duplications:  {a_6,a_9,a_10} and  {a_6,a_10,a_9} give same result.  How can ı we get rid of duplications at this final stage. I used DeleteDuplicates but not worked.

Comment: @gunes, does `MapAt[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort], {All, 2}]@
 delete1b[sol[3, 2], {{a[6], a[7], ___}}]` give the desired result?

Comment: the previous code works I appreciate a lot @kglr  I just want to ask you about usage of delete2b Let me give example: In  sol[3, 2], as you may see there are some results which contain empty set. How can we use your command  delete2b to drop all the entries of this kind of results.  For example   In  sol[3, 2]   we have,  {{b_1,b_1},{},},    {{b_2,b_2},{}}   , {{b_3,b_3},{}}.  these all 3 results contain empty sets. How can we drop these 3 results and similar ones?

Comment: @gunes, try composing `delete2b` with `DeleteCases[{{__},{}}]`, i.e., use `delete2c = DeleteCases[{{__},{}}]@*delete2b`

Comment: many thanks @kglr Sometimes I need to use delete1b and delete2b command at the same time.  For instance, For  sol[3, 2]  I use following way

Result1 = 
  MapAt[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort], {All, 2}]@
   delete1b[sol[3, 2], 
    Alternatives @@   {{a[6], a[9], ___}, {a[1], a[10], ___} } ] ;
Result2 = 
  MapAt[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort], {All, 2}]@
   delete2b[Result1, 
    Alternatives @@   {{b[1], b[2], ___}, {b[2], b[5], ___} } ] ;    is there an other way that may suggest me.?

Comment: thanks @kglr you solved duplication problem for  delete1b  for " indexed a" type elements.  I also have  duplication problem "indexed b type elements" I try to adapt your code for command delete2b but not worked. For instance, I use MapAt[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort], {All, 2}]@delete2b[sol[3, 4], 
  Alternatives @@   {{b[6], b[9], ___}, {b[1], b[4], ___} } ]  I have  ouputs : {{b_1,b_2,b_2,b_5},{{a_6,a_7,a_12},{a_6,a_9,a_10}}}  and  {{b_1,b_2,b_5,b_2},{{a_6,a_7,a_12},{a_6,a_9,a_10}}}  but since {b_1,b_2,b_5,b_2} and {b_1,b_2,b_2,b_5} is just duplication. How can we solve this at this stage